# Grouping all in one tuple in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have a table EMP with employees id and their hireyear. And I have to get the amount of hired employees in lets say the the years 2002 and 2000. The output table should als contain the amount of hired employees in the whole time.

So the last is easy. I just have to write:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) AS GLOBELAMOUNT FROM EMP;
```

But how do I count the amount of hired employees in 2002?
I could write the following:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) AS HIREDIN2002 FROM EMP WHERE YEAR = 2002;
```

But how do I combine this in one tuple with the data above?

Maybe I should group the data by Hireyear first and then count it? But can not really imagine how I count the data for several years.

Hope u guys can help me.

Cheers,

Andrej

Comment: You've tagged this both with MySQL and SQL Server. Which is it? Could make a big difference to the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Use *conditional aggregation*, e.g.:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) AS GLOBELAMOUNT,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN YEAR=2000 THEN 1 END) AS  HIREDIN2000,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN YEAR=2002 THEN 1 END) AS  HIREDIN2002 
FROM EMP;
```

Answer (score 0):

In Microsoft SQL Server (Transact-SQL) at least, you can use a **windowed** aggregate function like this:

```
Select  Distinct 
        Year
        ,count(Id) over (Partition by Year)  as CountHiredInYear
        ,count(Id) over ()                   as CountTotalHires
From    EMP
```

This gives something like:

```
Year | CountHiredInYear |  CountTotalHires
2005 | 3                |  12
2006 | 4                |  12
2007 | 5                |  12
```

Another SQL Server specific approach is the `With Rollup` keyword.

```
Select   Year
         ,count(Id) as CountHires
From     Emp
Group by Year
With Rollup
```

This adds a summary line for each level of grouping, with the total value for that set of rows. So here, you'd get an extra row where Year was `NULL`, with the value `12`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use two (or more) inline queries:

```
SELECT
  (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM EMP) AS GLOBELAMOUNT,
  (SELECT COUNT(id) FROM EMP WHERE YEAR = 2002) AS HIREDIN2002
```

or a CROSS JOIN:

```
SELECT GLOBELAMOUNT, HIREDIN2002
FROM
  (SELECT COUNT(id) AS GLOBELAMOUNT FFROM EMP) g CROSS JOIN
  (SELECT COUNT(id) AS HIREDIN2002 FROM EMP WHERE YEAR = 2002) h
```